# Java Drools Object Assignment With a Colon?

Tags: java, syntax, drools

I'm learning Java and Drools so that i can edit an existing codebase, I've encountered some syntax i believe is simply assigning a variable/object but i'm uncertain and i'd appreciate some clarity and insight before i incorrectly apply and rely on it.

```
RULE "Rule1"

    WHEN
        result : Result()   
        policy : Policy()   

    THEN
        logger.info("Running Rule1");
        retract(result);
END
```

It's the "xxx : xxx()" bit i'm uncertain about..
i try searching, but i end up with static declaration etc

is it the same as "xxx = new xxx();" or "xxx : xxx();" ?

My previous coding experience is with PHP and C#, thanks.

Comment: This is a basic topic which is explained in the Drools manual you need to study before you try to understand any code. Also, understanding (at least) basic Java is essential *before* you touch anything in the codebase. - And, no, neither a variable binding (`xxx: ...`) nor a pattern (`... Xyz()`) is a "static declaration".

Comment: I appreciate there is a "right way to do it" but i'm in a position where i have to do this work without any knowledge transfer and i'm up against a time limit.  I understand enough to build and run the environment, but there are just a couple of language nuances i need help with as working backwards is not as simple as working forwards.

the static declaration comment was because when i search for this, i get responses talking about the double colon or ternary.

i'm asking for help, not a lecture thanks

Comment: Do you want me to copy-paste the text from the manual?

Comment: At your suggestion, i tried skimming the manual myself to find what you were on about, but i didn't have much luck.  
If you would be so kind, i'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pattern element is the most important Conditional Element. It can potentially match on each fact that is inserted in the working memory.

A pattern contains of zero or more constraints and has an optional pattern binding.

[*patternBinding* **:**] *pattern type* **(** [ *constraints* ] **)**

In its simplest form, with no constraints, a pattern matches against a fact of the given type. In the following case the type is Person, which means that the pattern will match against all Person objects in the Working Memory:

```
Person()
```

For referring to the matched object, use a pattern binding variable such as $p. (The '$' is not mandatory, just a convention.)

```
$p: Person()
```

A property can be bound to a variable:

```
Person( $firstAge : age ) // binding
```

Just note that "binding" isn't "assigning"; a "binding variable" isn't a "variable" as it is known in C# or PHP.